# Get reactive value from subscription in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In Meteor, how do I properly return a value from a property (in this case **response**) from a collection so that I can send it to a data propert? I have tried the following function:

```
Responses: function(answer) {
    return Responses.findOne({answerId: answer.hash.answer});
}
```

Which I call in the spacebars template as:

```
data-selected="{{Responses answer=_id}}
```

When I look at the HTML it says that the data-selected="[object object]" which is not super surprising but I can't figure out how to return just the response value from the match. I can add .response onto the end and it works but gives an expected 'undefined' error I know that it is not reactive. I have seen people use wrapasync but that was for methods, not subscriptions. I should note that there are several responses, so the code would have to be suitable inside a #for loop of answers which the responses variable is keeping track of the input from each user separately.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about data-selected="{{Responses answer=_id}}". Since you're already inside a for loop your html code can simply look like this:

```
data-selected="{{Responses}}"
```

Inside your helper function you can then say:

```
var myResponse = Responses.findOne({answerId: this._id}).response;
if (myResponse != null){
    return myResponse;
else {
    return "";
}
```

When the page is still loading and the data is not yet available, myResponse is still null, so the helper returns the empty string "". Shortly thereafter the data becomes available and your data gets returned, without any error in your console.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the this._id tip. That really simplifies things. Adding .response to the end gives this error: "Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined" but then it does print the correct value to the data helper, so I think it is just an asynchronous problem but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Glad to help. What you could do is put Responses.findOne({answerId: this._id}).response in a variable first, and check if that is null, and instead return nothing if it is. It probably takes a little time for the data to become available, so this if-statement prevents the error and automatically refreshes the helper when the data is available. You'll never notice the minimal time frame where the helper returns nothing, because that's part of the page loading. I updated my answer to reflect this solution.